# What is the time complexity of the classic Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for finding cliques?

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, clique

Bron-Kerbosch is an algorithm to find maximal cliques in a undirected graph. In pseudocode it's the following (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm)):

```
BronKerbosch1(R, P, X):
   if P and X are both empty:
       report R as a maximal clique
   for each vertex v in P:
       BronKerbosch1(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
       P := P \ {v}
       X := X ⋃ {v}
```

I have read that the time complexity of some modified versions of this algorithm is $O(3^{n/3})$, but I can't seem to find the running time complexity of the simple version anywhere.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I asked the question without logging in and my edit needs to be peer reviewed before becoming visible.

Comment: Consider a complete graph (with an edge between each pair of vertices).  I expect you should be able to work out the running time.  I suspect it will be something like $O(2^n)$, but try and work through it yourself, and if you can solve it, feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

The exact running time of the algorithm depends on implementation details. The number of recursive calls to the procedure, however, is easily seen to be exactly the number of *ordered cliques*, that is, the number of ordered sequences of distinct vertices which form cliques. In particular, if the graph is complete then the number of recursive calls is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \approx e \cdot n!.
$$
When the maximum clique has size $k$, the number of recursive calls is at most
$$
1 + n + n(n-1) + \cdots + n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) \leq 2n^k.
$$
Conversely, if you run the algorithm on a complete $k$-partite graph, then the number of recursive calls will be $\Omega(n^k)$.